# How to tell if popen() was successful?

Tags: c++, c, shell, popen

How can you know if `popen()` succeeded/done running the shell or failed?

Comment: What do you mean by "running the shell?" Have you checked the popen man page?

Comment: Documentation... "Upon successful completion, popen() shall return a pointer to an open stream that can be used to read or write to the pipe. Otherwise, it shall return a null pointer and may set errno to indicate the error"

Comment: Check the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen).

Comment: @user1104856,  What does 'success' mean to you? I can see three scenarios: (1) The program runs fully successfully with a successful exit status of `0`, or (2) `cat non_existent_file`, or (3) a more catastrophic failure where popen can't even call fork or pipe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[popen return value](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/popen.html):

> Upon successful completion, popen() shall return a pointer to an open
>   stream that can be used to read or write to the pipe. Otherwise, it
>   shall return a null pointer and may set errno to indicate the error.

```
fp = popen("ls *", "r");
if (fp == NULL)
    /* Handle error */;
```

Comment: Thanks! Just what i need to know :D

Comment: And exactly what you could have found by reading the man page `man popen`.  You'll save yourself (and the rest of us) a lot of time in the future by checking your local documentation before asking here.

Comment: Remember, that the command which is run by the shell might fail, perhaps trying to `cat` a file which doesn't exist. In this case, `popen` is succesful. You would need to use `pclose` to get the return value from the shell.

Comment: @ Keith Thompson  i did, but you are right. @ Aaron McDaid i'm doing so: status = pclose(fp); :)

Comment: @AaronMcDaid - So what do I do if I need to check the return code of the shell BEFORE closing the stream ?

Comment: Suppose the shell command is to compile a file. The command will get executed and it can terminate either with a compilation success or with a compilation error. But in both cases the `popen` will think that the command was succesfully executed. How to differentiate between these cases?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean running popen in C code, you can check the man page. It says that popen will return NULL if it fails, and it returns a file stream otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is not really definitive.

For example, asking `popen()` to execute an invalid command or image would just return a valid file pointer (with nothing to read). Meanwhile, the resulting error message from the shell is redirected to the parent's `stderr`.

`popen()` will indeed return NULL when it's unable to spawn the shell, which in common situations is an unusual case.